# i want to filter category wise post on same page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

filter category post wise on same page in WordPress if  i click category 
  plastic i want result plastic product

for example product category

1.plastic
   2.metallic
   3.silver
   showing image 
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDkat.png)

post div

```
<?php
 global $post;
 $myposts = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'numberposts' => '999',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    )
);

?>
```

sidebar div

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $curVal = "";
    $myposts = get_posts(
                array(
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                    'numberposts' => '999',
                    'orderby' => 'product_category',
                    'order' => 'ASC'
                )
            );                 
?>

<ul>

    <?php 
        foreach($myposts as $post){ 
            if($curVal != get_field('franchise_category')) { ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo  home_url( $wp->request ); ?>?cat=<?php echo get_field('product_category'); ?>">
                    <?php echo get_field('product_category'); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php }$curVal = get_field('product_category');} ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: What's your question? Please state it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

1st if you want to get all posts with this query use:

```
'numberposts' => -1,// this will return all available, right now you are passing a string 999 - '999'
```

2nd - you're not [setting up your post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/setup_postdata/) data and [restoring context of the template tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) Try this:

```
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );

...
...
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Edit your code and see the result.